# Can someone explain the syntax of this line of Solidity code?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

There's so much I don't understand about this line of code, is anyone able to break it down for me?

```
(bool success, ) = msg.sender.call{value: balance}("");
```

What I don't grasp:

- The commas around the bool declaration
- The comma after success
- Curly braces before the parentheses after msg.sender.call
- The reasoning behind passing an empty string (is it being passed to msg.send.call?)

I find documentation for Solidity very hard to grasp, are there any resources concerning just the syntax of the language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - The commas around the bool declaration
> - The comma after success

`msg.sender.call` returns two values

```
(bool success, bytes memory data) = msg.sender.call{value: balance}("");
```

if you do not need the data, you dont specify the name. that is why

```
(bool success, )
```

> - Curly braces before the parentheses after msg.sender.call

it is syntax to specify the amount of ether to send. before it was like this

```
contract.call.value(...)(...)
```

you could also pass `gas` parameter here

```
{value: balance, gas: 1000000}
```

> - The reasoning behind passing an empty string (is it being passed to msg.send.call?)

`call` defined on address type. `address` can be `contract` or `externally owned accounts (accounts that users hold their balance)`

If you are calling `contract.call`, "" calls the `fallback` function on `msg.sender` contract address. remember, contract can call other contracts, so `msg.sender` can be a contract address. if you want to call the specific function on `msg.sender`, you have to pass the function signature. For example, if you want to call `test()` with its parameter types

```
// 1 for uint value, msg.sender for address value
msg.sender.call{value: balance}(abi.encodeWithSignature("test(uint,address)", 1, msg.sender))
```

`call` is also used to transfer fund to an externally owned account. in this case there is not a function to call, in this case we have "". Imagine you have a contract for an ecommerce contract, a user buys the product and user sends the price to the owner

```
(bool success, ) = owner.call{value: item.price}("");
require(success, "Transfer failed");
```

Comment: So `msg.sender.call{value: balance}("")` uses the default callback function on msg.sender; if you wanted to use a different callback, you would replace the empty string with a string containing the target function's signature. The part in curly braces is how you specify how much ethereum to send in the transaction, in this case the value of `balance`.